# A better way to lookup & categorize data besides IFS and REGEXMATCH

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a way to categorize data based on the keywords it contains.

Right now, I am using IFs with RegexMatch. But it's quite clustered & makes the sheet heavy when I have a larger amount of categories and keywords.

[image: Ifs and RegexMatch]

The formula I am using:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(A2,$F$2),$E$2,REGEXMATCH(A2,$F$3),$E$3)
```

If anyone knows any better/cleaner way or different formula to streamline this process, please let me know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A&IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(F2:F))/0), 
 IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(F2:F))/0)&TRANSPOSE(F2:F)), E2:E, ))),,9^9)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the formula! That seems like a longer formula than mine. Can this scale up if I have more data? or we would have to write more to meet the increase of dataset. Thanks

Comment: @RexNguyen try it. it uses open ranges so it should work as is

Answer (score 0):

to lookup things, there is nothing better than vLOOKUP...

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, E:E)), E1:F, 2, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do we have a way to group all the criteria (a,b,c,d, etc.) together? Since there are a lot of criteria and putting each of them in a cell like that can make the list very long. Thanks.

Comment: @RexNguyen how big is your dataset?

Comment: I have around 22 categories with around 10-22 criteria for each category.