# ArrayFormula and Categorize Data in Google Sheets using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I'm following this [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97405/how-to-categorize-data-in-google-spreadsheet-using-regular-expressions) to categorize data in Google Sheets using regular expressions.

The person who wrote the answer was able to get the formula to automatically write down the category in column D.

I assume they used ArrayFormula to achieve it, but I can't seem to get it done. Or they just paste the formula to each cell of the column. I'm not sure.

The formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:B,MATCH(TRUE,ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(C2,INDIRECT("A"&2&":A"&3+COUNTA(B$2:B)))),0),2))
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18tjkqpQET4oQ8yuZ0hI7nB60pTrFw_7ycPfX69qsY3o/edit?usp=sharing) is the sample Sheet I made as an example.

What I am looking for is to categorize data in column C based on the keywords in column A. The category result is written in Column D

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: There are many unknowns here. I suggest that you share a link to a sample spreadsheet with *realistic* data examples representing your actual data. For instance, will Col A always join only *single words*, or might some of them be expressions made up of multiple words? Will they be enclose in quotes as you show here? Why are you using periods in Col A? Are those supposed to represent regular expressions? Does case matter? Why do you have "small house" listed twice in Col C, and why does only one of them get labeled in Col D? Give more examples and explain everything in detail for best results.

Comment: @ErikTyler Thanks for answering. I just updated my question. I just updated the question. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18tjkqpQET4oQ8yuZ0hI7nB60pTrFw_7ycPfX69qsY3o/edit?usp=sharing) is the sample sheet I made. Thanks!

Comment: Sharing the spreadsheet is a start. However, you have not answered any of the many questions I asked above. You haven't added more data for testing purposes. And you haven't confirmed that this is *realistic* data that represents the actual data you will be working with.

Comment: Thanks for helping. At the beginning of the question, I added the post that I was following. Perhaps that can explain it better than I.

1) ColA contains the keywords that when detected, will write out the category in Col B. For example, the sentence "small house" has the word "small" in it, so the category of it is "Size". If the sentence contains "blue", then category is "Color", etc.

2) I fixed Col A into blue|white|red This seems to work for my case. I'm new in this so my apology.

3) Case matters.

4) ColC is where I put the different sentences to categorize them.

Comment: What I am looking for is when I type a link in ColC. The formula will detects keywords in ColA with appropriate category in Col B and write the answer to Col D

Comment: What should happen if you enter 'shredded documents' in Col C? This contains `red`. What if you were to enter "small white mouse" in Col C? Should it pick up the first category only or both? I hope it is clear by now that this isn't as simple as you might have thought. In addition, each Stack post should be self-contained. Asking the volunteer contributors here to go and read/study some other post is adding extra work for others who are not being paid for the help offered. Help us help you by including all relevant details in your own post, per Stack guidelines.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of it. I don't have enough reputation points to ask directly in the post. So I hope someone might know the answer to it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**
*see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73294601/19529694) with similar answer*

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="",,TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(C2:C&IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(A2:A))/0), 
 IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A))/0)&TRANSPOSE(A2:A)), B2:B, ))),,9^9)))))
```

[image]

Comment: your formula will only work for as many rows in Col C as there are entries in Cols A and B. Right now, you *happen* to have as many rows in Col C as in A and B. But if you added more entries to Col C without adding any more entries to Cols A and B, I think you will find that no results appear for the later listings in Col C. That is because Google Sheets will be trying to keep all array lengths (in rows) parallel. In fact, your formula will only return a match if the match is in the same row as the Col-C entry for this reason. But the OP should thank you for the time you put in!

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler thanks for your insight, I tested the scenario you Pointed out, and it work's as expected see [This](https://i.imgur.com/AT1w0lX.png),  no errors, and 
the formula will only work for as many rows in Col C as there are entries in Cols A and B, thats the point why he kept the categories in this form `blue|white|red`, if there is any thing i did'nt address please share a screenshot of your resut.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the OP's goal, and you may be understanding it correctly. I thought the goal was to indicate *per listing in Col C* what the category (or categories) are *for each individual listing in Col C*. But it seems, per your assessment, that the goal is to simply list whether a category was used *at all anywhere in Col C* and, if so, to list it only once in Col D.

Comment: No no, let's keep it simple, |Unique Categories| Are Categories and |Join of Variables| Are sub Categories, and they need to be in the same row, and ... Phrases to Screen is changing every time, I think you want to do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73294801/19529694) follow the answer and you will find the OP is limited due to large categories and criteria for each category.

Comment: @ErikTyler To be clear, the approach chosen by the OP seems a little off to me. If there is a better way, post it as an answer to this question or as an article/question.